# Query data that starts with numbers only

Tags: solr

Hello I have a field in Solr that start with 1 or more digits.
For e.g

- 123Adam- R Test
- 2Adam Test
- 534534As
- **ABCSD**
- **A person**

How can I configure a field type, such that it will match any data that starts with numbers only? Please suggest.

I created this type but it is other way around it strips the numbers leaves the characters
for e.g data "123ABCSD" It end up "ABCSD". I would like to issue query q=0:9 or somefield:*.* should return rows that starts with numbers only.

```
<fieldType name="numbersfirst" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^[0-9]+([^[0-9]]*)" replacement="" replace="all"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: If you want to store into that field  only words starting with numbers then change your db-data-config.xml query or if you want to retrieve only words starting with numbers then query using wildcards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a separate boolean field that just stores whether your field starts with a number.  Then when you're indexing, just parse the field yourself and set your boolean field accordingly.  Then it's a simple query against that boolean field.

Comment: I just did that. See below.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
     <script>
    <![CDATA[
            function findInfoStartingWithNumber(row)    {

                var patternStr = "^[0-9]+([^[0-9]]*)";
                var pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(patternStr);
                var inputStr = (row.get('name') == null ? "" : row.get('name').toString().trim().toUpperCase());
                var matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
                var matchFound = matcher.find(); // false                   
                row.put('StartsWithNumber',matchFound);

                return row;
            }
    ]]>
</script>
<entity name="MaterialInfo" transformer="script:findInfoStartingWithNumber" query="">
```

In case anybody wants to know where the above elements fall under the db-data-config.xml element structure

```
<dataconfig>
 <datasource>
  <script>
  </script>
  <document>
  <entity></entity>
 </document>
</datasource>
```