# solr query for field value starting with a number

Tags: ajax, solr

I have to modify a query that searches for a value starting with a letter (relevant snippet fo the query): `&fq=Organization:"+letter+"*&`

If I pass 'A' as the letter param I'll get 'ABC Hardware', something that start with an A.

How would i modify the letter variable to return only something that starts with a number, as '1A Widgets'.

Tried things like `letter = '[0 TO 5]'`, but I honestly have no idea if I'm on the right track with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046691/query-data-that-starts-with-numbers-only/8051068#8051068)

For cases like this, my favourite approach is to index another boolean field called "StartsWithNumber" and then it's a simple boolean filter.  This might not work for you if you can't reindex all of your documents.

For a brute force approach, you could do something like:

```
fq=Organization:0* OR Organization:1* OR Organization:2* OR .. etc
```

Not pretty, but fq's get cached so at least it should be fast.

Comment: Brute is good, thanks for saving the day :-), sorry about the dupe questions if that's the case, didn't realize it.